# GZip compression and cache control from PHP not htaccess or Apache conf

Tags: php, apache2, compression, gzip, cache-control

I have the following piece of code in my PHP script that generates the HTML for all the pages of my website:

```
    if( !headers_sent() and !ob_get_length() ) {
        $days = 30;
        header('Last-Modified: ' . date( 'D, d M Y H:i:s', $mtime ));
        header('Expires: ' . date( 'D, d M Y H:i:s', strtotime('+' . $days . ' days') ) . ' GMT');
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=' . 60*24*$days . ', public, must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        ini_set( 'zlib.output_compression_level', 1 );
        ob_start( 'ob_gzhandler' );

        header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=' . strtolower( $this->PageCharset ) );
        header( 'Connection: Keep-alive' );
    }
```

Anyway I can't understand one thing: does this apply also to all images, javascripts and CSSs or only to pages?

In .htaccess I know I can apply the following directives to control cache and compressions for all types of files including css, js, images, etc. But my shared hosting service doesn't allow to use some of those directives (Header, SetEnvIfNoCase). So what can I do to control caching and compressions for all filetypes without using Apache directives?

```
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
        ExpiresActive On
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 days"
        ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
        ExpiresByType text/plain "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType application/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
            Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
        </FilesMatch>
        <FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
            Header set Cache-Control "public"
        </FilesMatch>
        <FilesMatch "\.(css)$">
            Header set Cache-Control "public"
        </FilesMatch>
        <FilesMatch "\.(js)$">
            Header set Cache-Control "private"
        </FilesMatch>
        <FilesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">
            Header set Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate"
        </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

        # Don’t compress
        SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
        SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:exe|t?gz|zip|bz2|sit|rar)$ no-gzip dont-vary

        #Dealing with proxy servers
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            Header append Vary User-Agent
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
```

Thank you.

Comment: since php's generating the headers, it'll apply only to output from PHP scripts. unless you're serving up your images/css/whatever through php, these `header()` calls will NOT affect them.

Comment: That's exactly what I knew. So, my question is: what can I do on a server where I can't use some directives? thanks.

Comment: either get permission to use those directives, or start serving up everything through php scripts, where you can output any headers you want.